# React does not recognize the `totalPrice and totalQuantity` prop on a DOM element and Maximum update depth exceeded Error

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a code to calculate total quantity and total Price of cart. But there is a problem to send a referance to child component. (App.js -> Navigation.js -> CartProcess.js -> CartList.js , App.js-> CartList.js(For Routing)) 
CartProcess has a link shown below. Here is the problem shown below.

**React does not recognize the `totalQuantity` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `totalquantity` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.**

**React does not recognize the `totalPrice` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `totalprice` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.**

```
<DropdownItem>
   <Link to="/cart"
    totalQuantity={ this.props.totalQuantity}
    totalPrice={ this.props.totalPrice }
   >Cart Detail</Link>
</DropdownItem>
```

App.js has also included CartList Component to show cart detail.

render part

```
    <Route exact path="/cart" render={
                  routeProps => (
                    <CartList
                      {...routeProps}
                      cart={this.state.cart}
                      removeFromCart={this.removeFromCart}
                      totalQuantity={this.totalQuantity}
                      totalPrice={this.totalPrice}
                    />
                  )
                } />

  }
```

When I call totalQuantity and totalPrice function from parent component like this order.

```
App.js <- Navigation.js <- CartProcess.js
```

I got an error shown below.

**Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

CartList.js

```
renderTotalPriceAndTotalQuantity(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Alert color="primary">
                Total Price : { this.props.totalPrice() }
            </Alert>
            <Alert color="secondary">
                Total Quantity : { this.props.totalQuantity() }
            </Alert>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

App.js

```
totalQuantity = () => {
    console.log("totalQuantity");

    this.setState({
      totalQuantity: this.state.cart.reduce(
        (sum = 0, cartItem) => sum + cartItem.quantity,
        0
      )
    });

    console.log(this.state.totalQuantity);
  }

  totalPrice = () => {
    console.log("totalPrice");

    this.setState({
      totalPrice: this.state.cart.reduce(
        (sum = 0, cartItem) => sum + cartItem.quantity * cartItem.product.unitPrice,
        0
      )
    });

    console.log(this.state.totalPrice);
  }
```

How can I fix the problems?

Here is my project link
[Project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l-kMTTnC2rTwqzLIxU8DsIV1M-z65SlW)

To get all categories and product list , use

```
json-server --watch db.json
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CartList.js` you are actually calling the function in html which is causing this issue. Try to do like this:

```
renderTotalPriceAndTotalQuantity(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Alert color="primary">
                Total Price : { this.props.totalPrice }
            </Alert>
            <Alert color="secondary">
                Total Quantity : { this.props.totalQuantity }
            </Alert>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I cannot see the result. How can I see this.state.totalPrice and this.state.totalQuantity in the Alert

Comment: where are you rendering the cartList function?

Comment: I edited my post to show my render function in App.jsb and also share my project link.